# Cleaning up text files with sed?

Tags: sed

I have a bunch of text files that need cleaning up. Example

```
    `E..4B?@.@...
..9J5.....P0.z.n9.9.. ........
 .k#a..5
E...y^@.r...J5..

E...y_@.r...J5..
..9.P..n9..0.z............
….2..3..9…n7…..@.yr`
```

Is there any way sed can do this? Like notice weird patterns?

Comment: Define "weird" and post your expected output given that sample input.

Comment: this text is in that file type? This does not seem "clean" actually sounds like "extract".

Answer (score 4):

For this answer, I will assume that you have access to standard unix/linux tools.

Your file might be in some word-processor format.  If so, the best way to get rid of the junk is to open it with that program.  You may be able to find out which with `file`:

```
$ file mysteryfile 
mysteryfile: Composite Document File V2 Document, Little Endian, Os: Windows, Version 6.1 ....
```

If that doesn't work, there is a standard unix utility for extracting text from binary files.  It is called `strings`:

```
$ strings mysteryfile
Some
Recovered Text
...
```

The behavior of `strings` can be fine tuned with several options.  See `man strings`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `strings`; that is quite suitable if you can't work out the source format of the document, or you don't have the tools needed to manipulate the document.  It isn't perfect; it wouldn't handle UTF-16 encoded data, I think.  But it's a good first step.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for that!  I looked into the character set issue a little further.  From its manpage, `strings` claims that it supports UTF-16 if the `-el` (or -eb?) option is given  (I did not test that). Also, according to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863986/gnu-binutils-strings-utf-8-instead-of-utf-16-or-ascii , `strings` works on UTF-8 if it is given the `-eS` option.  I tested the UTF-8 option _lightly_ and it seemed to work.

Comment: Interesting; I'd not looked at it in any detail in…oh, this millennium…and things change, of course.

Comment: Sadly, `strings` still doesn't support UTF-8. I ran across this question while finding that out. Ultimately, I just wrote my own UTF-8 strings. https://github.com/hackerb9/utf8strings